# How to mock value mongoose find with method lean and not using lean in Jest Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jestjs

I want to ask about mock mongoose find.

Let's say I have 2 method mongoose model find like this :

```
let resultA = await ModelA.find()
```

```
and let resultB = await ModelA.find().lean().
```

These 2 is called in different utils. I tried with mockImplementation like this :

```
mockMongooseFind.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
lean: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(resultValueMockFind),
      };
    });
I
```

t only work when called method lean but not work when not called method lean.
The result with lean is proper data. But when get the result when not use lean is will be like this :

```
{ lean:
       { [Function: mockConstructor]
         _isMockFunction: true,
         getMockImplementation: [Function],
         mock: [Getter/Setter],
         mockClear: [Function],
         mockReset: [Function],
         mockRestore: [Function],
         mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
         mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
         mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
         mockReturnValue: [Function],
         mockResolvedValue: [Function],
         mockRejectedValue: [Function],
         mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
         mockImplementation: [Function],
         mockReturnThis: [Function],
         mockName: [Function],
         getMockName: [Function] } }.
```

How I make the proper mock for this case?

Get the better function for mock the mongoose method